# Changing window size of Geany's execute (F5) option

Tags: python, ide, geany

I'm using Geany 0.18 for python developing and am in general really satisfied, but there is one little thing, that's still bugging me:

I usually use the F5 (Build-->Execute) option to test my scripts, the appearing window is rather small, and if my script prints lines which are too long they are hard to read. I would like to change the default-window size of the little one popping up if I hit F5, but I haven't found anything to accomplish this.

Is this possible at all ?

Thanks
Mischa

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To solve that problem I added additional parameters to terminal command that geany runs.

- In Geany go to preferences (Edit->Preferences).
- Open Tools tab.
- There is an input field named Terminal where you can specify terminal program to use.
- I changed that to `"gnome-terminal --maximize"` to open terminal maximized.

For Gnome-Terminal you can find more window options running "gnome-terminal --help-window-options" from terminal.

Comment: The geometry options in particular are what you want here: http://www.xfree86.org/current/X.7.html#sect6

Answer (score 1):

In the window that pops up (if using windows) click on the white bar at the top (right click) this will open a menu, choose defaults then change font/font size etc.